# Firebase endAt() funky behaviour with orderByChild() when paging/infinite scroll

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, infinite-scroll

I am trying to load user's most recent posts first and page them in descending order but I am having trouble using `endAt().limitToLast()` with `orderByChild()`.

I can page the items fine using `startAt().limitToFirst()` with `orderByChild()` but I need to have my list load from the end... When performing my query using `endAt()` the orderByChild() seems to get ignored.

Here is my JSON for the `categories` node

```
{
  "-LY8EYaWHINB1khsIEvJ" : {
    "Recipies" : true,
    "username" : "User1"
  },
  "-LYDaIrnDKIWndMcLE-g" : {
    "Recipies" : true,
    "username" : "User4"
  },
  "-LY8Em4B6COFk3how5FC" : {
    "Buds" : true,
    "username" : "User2"
  },
  "-LY8Eq2E1muFcOBstODa" : {...},
  "-LY8Esi98QdhszIgvRRN" : {...},
  "-LY9OSc7u8wTNQaJ7BXL" : {...},
  "-LY8EymPGxK8Y_YnRfC0" : {...},
  "-LY8F0RrYbLNPpYwIuMX" : {...},
  "-LY8F3QfERAhOq3iW3jC" : {...},
}
```

Heres what my query looks like (note I need to fetch this from the bottom up):

```
  const fetchCategoryImages = (category, currentImages, lastKey) => {
      if (!lastKey) {
        return () => {
          firebase.database().ref('/categories')
            .orderByChild('Recipies' //this is the category)
            .endAt(true)
            .limitToLast(4)
            .on('value', snapshot => {
              const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val())
                 .sort()
                 .reverse();

              const results = arrayOfKeys
                .map((key) => snapshot.val()[key]);

              const createLastKey = arrayOfKeys[arrayOfKeys.length - 1];

              //just passing the initial data with redux here... (snapshot and lastKey...)
            });
        };
      } else {
         //subsequent fetch if there is a lastKey to reference start point
         return () => {
           firebase.database().ref('/categories')
             .orderByChild('Recipies' //this is the category)
             .endAt(true, '-LY9OSc7u8wTNQaJ7BXL' //this is the lastKey)
             .limitToLast(3)
             .on('value', snapshot => {
               const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val())
                  .sort()
                  .reverse()
                  .slice(1);

               const results = arrayOfKeys
                  .map((key) => snapshot.val()[key]);

               const createLastKey = arrayOfKeys[arrayOfKeys.length - 1];
               const concatImages = _.concat(currentImages, results);

               //passing the new data with redux here... (snapshot and lasy ley...)

               }
           });
        };
     };
```

All these problems go away when I simply switch the query to use `startAt().limitToFirst()` with `orderByChild()` instead.

Really appreciate all the help I can get with this issue, cheers!

Comment: There's a bit much going on in here, with values we don't know, making it hard to see where the problem comes from. Can you: 1) reproduce the problem in a snippet that doesn't depend on react/redux? 2) reproduce it with hard-coded values for `lastKey` and `category`? 3) share the minimal JSON with which to reproduce it (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey Frank! Thank you, I just updated my answer - hope this helps.

Comment: That helps, thanks for that. I'm still having a hard time understanding the exact problem though. 1) Can you reduce the code further to only show the case that doesn't work? 2) Can you reduce the description of the problem to only cover the case that doesn't work? I hope I'll be of more help this those changes.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I was going to delete this question due to the other one, I just saw your comment, sorry! I edited this question to match the other.

Comment: Don't delete an existing question to then repost it. Just clarify your original question. Reposting your own question again will get flagged and alert the moderators.

Comment: Okay good to know, thank you.

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen, is there anything else I can do to improve my question? I still haven’t had any luck with this it’s driving me bananas.

Comment: When you run the query with `.endAt(true, '-LY9OSc7u8wTNQaJ7BXL')`, I expect to see `-LY9OSc7u8wTNQaJ7BXL`, `-LY8Esi98QdhszIgvRRN` and `-LY8Eq2E1muFcOBstODa` (depending on their value for the `Recipies` property of course). Are those not the results you get?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes I was getting those results, I finally resolved this issue but I would love to hear why I need the startAt(true) as well. I have the exact same query working without it on another node so I'm quite uncertain about this. Just happy it works! Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, after trying ALMOST everything, it turns out all I had to do was add `startAt(true)` too. I am not to sure why, but it works. I have other queries that are pretty much the same as this that work without it - beats my... would love to know why I need this in order for it to work though.

here is my working code:

```
 const fetchCategoryImages = (category, currentImages, lastKey) => {
      if (!lastKey) {
        return () => {
          firebase.database().ref('/categories')
            .orderByChild('Recipies' //this is the category)
            //THE SOLUTION
            .startAt(true)
            .endAt(true)
            .limitToLast(4)
            .on('value', snapshot => {
          const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val())
             .sort()
             .reverse();

          const results = arrayOfKeys
            .map((key) => snapshot.val()[key]);

          const createLastKey = arrayOfKeys[arrayOfKeys.length - 1];

          //just passing the initial data with redux here... (snapshot and lastKey...)
        });
    };
  } else {
     //subsequent fetch if there is a lastKey to reference start point
     return () => {
       firebase.database().ref('/categories')
         .orderByChild('Recipies' //this is the category)
          //THE SOLUTION
          .startAt(true)
         .endAt(true, '-LY9OSc7u8wTNQaJ7BXL' //this is the lastKey)
         .limitToLast(3)
         .on('value', snapshot => {
           const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(snapshot.val())
              .sort()
              .reverse()
              .slice(1);

           const results = arrayOfKeys
              .map((key) => snapshot.val()[key]);

           const createLastKey = arrayOfKeys[arrayOfKeys.length - 1];
           const concatImages = _.concat(currentImages, results);

           //passing the new data with redux here... (snapshot and lasy ley...)

           }
       });
    };
 };
```

Comment: Hmm... that sort of makes sense, since you only want results that *havE* the `Recipies` property. My main concern is that I can't reproduce it. See my answer for data, code and link (since the code won't fit in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

I just test with this JSON:

```
{
  "-LY8EYaWHINB1khsIEvJ" : {
    "Recipies" : true,
    "username" : "User1"
  },
  "-LY8Em4B6COFk3how5FC" : {
    "Buds" : true,
    "username" : "User2"
  },
  "-LY8Eq2E1muFcOBstODa" : {
    "Buds" : true,
    "username" : "User3"
  },
  "-LY8Esi98QdhszIgvRRN" : {
    "Buds" : true,
    "username" : "User4"
  },
  "-LY8EymPGxK8Y_YnRfC0" : {
    "Buds" : true,
    "username" : "User5"
  },
  "-LY8F0RrYbLNPpYwIuMX" : {
    "Buds" : true,
    "username" : "User6"
  },
  "-LY8F3QfERAhOq3iW3jC" : {
    "Receipies" : true,
    "username" : "User7"
  },
  "-LY9OSc7u8wTNQaJ7BXL" : {
    "Buds" : true,
    "username" : "User8"
  },
  "-LYDaIrnDKIWndMcLE-g" : {
    "Recipies" : true,
    "username" : "User8"
  }
}
```

And this code:

```
ref.orderByChild('Buds')
  .endAt(true, '-LY9OSc7u8wTNQaJ7BXL')
  .limitToLast(3)
  .once('value', snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(child => {
      console.log(child.key+": "+JSON.stringify(child.val()));
    })
  })
```

Live sample: https://jsbin.com/zigofok/edit?js,console

When run this prints:

> "-LY8EymPGxK8Y_YnRfC0: {\"Buds\":true,\"username\":\"User5\"}"
>
> "-LY8F0RrYbLNPpYwIuMX: {\"Buds\":true,\"username\":\"User6\"}"
>
> "-LY9OSc7u8wTNQaJ7BXL: {\"Buds\":true,\"username\":\"User8\"}"

Note how it skips `User7` in there, since that user doesn't have the `Buds` property.